# Are WinForms events exhaustively defined anywhere?

Tags: .net, winforms

I seem to spend a large portion of my event-handling time in WinForms learning about its events through experimentation and trial-and-error.

For example, the definition of the Control.Resize event (from MSDN's [.NET 4.0 - Control.Resize Event page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

**"Occurs when the control is resized."**

As it turns out, 'resize' appears to have a rather specific definition in WinForms parlance. The event is not fired whenever the control changes size (for that, you have to listen to the [SizeChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

This isn't immediately obvious from the MSDN documentation, and fumbling my way through these events and 'special definitions' results in a lot of wasted time and unexpected behavior. Is there a central repository for an exhaustive definition of WinForms events (when they fire, when they don't fire but you might expect they would, firing order, etc)?

Comment: Use the Source Luke: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MSDN is the closest to a reference you will come, unfortunately the exact info is a bit scattered.

Perhaps reading a good book on the subject will provide you with enough background knowledge on WinForms, to be able to find the right definitions and references quicker / or understand the quirks. A good one might be [Petzold's Programming Microsoft Windows Forms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621535). It might be a bit old, but nothing really new has happened in WinForms since it came out. The reason why I am suggesting this one, is that Petzold is the author of Programming Windows, which is the C/Win32 API counterpart, and this one is generally regarded as *the* book for Windows programmers.